# How to run ms sql server script in java?

Tags: java, sql-server

I am using this code.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename.getText()));
String str;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

    sb.append(str + "\n ");
}
in.close();
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sb.toString());
System.err.println("Script Executed");
```

but gives
`Exception:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:     Incorrect syntax near 'GO'`.

Some code of query is:

```
USE [Medico]
GO
/****** Object:  User [medico1]    Script Date: 02/05/2015 19:19:40 ******/
CREATE USER [medico1] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
/****** Object:  User [medico]    Script Date: 02/05/2015 19:19:40 ******/
CREATE USER [medico] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[employee]    Script Date: 02/05/2015 19:19:51           ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employee](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](100) NULL,
[code] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[address] [varchar](max) NULL,
[city] [varchar](100) NULL,
[state] [varchar](50) NULL,
[phone] [varchar](50) NULL,
[mob] [varchar](50) NULL,
[email] [varchar](100) NULL,
[enrolldate] [date] NULL,
[qualification] [varchar](100) NULL,
[status] [varchar](100) NULL,
[description] [varchar](max) NULL,
[designation] [varchar](100) NULL,
[etype] [varchar](100) NULL,
[password] [varchar](100) NULL,
[username] [varchar](250) NULL,
[usercode] [varchar](250) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[code] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =      OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
 SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
 GO
```

Comment: What is the query? `System.out.println(sb.toString());`

Comment: Query is to long . i am not able to post it.

Comment: is that  your script or you copied from some other file? I asked because these kind of create table scripts usually run outside java program to create required tables for program.

Comment: This script is generated by sql server 2008, but not in same computer . also it is not complete script . i am not able to post all code

Answer (score 0):

To create all the necessary objects from that script, open `Sql Server Management studio` and run that script. That is the safest method to create all the objects

Comment: ok , is their any way to run script file in java code . which is generated in ms sql server 2008.

Comment: because i have to create all  objects(tables) using java program and their are lots of table.

Comment: what is the size of that script file?

Comment: https://doc-14-3s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/h37otn3qun49mgo01fi29qsb0qr3dqrq/nbtvuktjjs702lcogkrc6lemfdj0jq2k/1423202400000/05236283936033270710/05236283936033270710/0B3m9I-Hyr_czMUkxaGpneDJKLTQ?e=download&nonce=to9h8257imtt0&user=05236283936033270710&hash=b247kqt4b3tg88ugta7fveok1nkhepap

Comment: you just need run this script to create tables, keys etc, or you want to run this script from java?

Comment: if you jut want to create required tables,keys etc use sql server management studio to run this scipt.

Comment: this code is working by removing all GO keywords from script file